# Create a view with special forms (wave) in React Native

Tags: react-native, frontend, expo

I am posting here today because I am having trouble finding ressources for react native concerning the integration of "wavy" designs such as the following UI:
I could ask the designer to send it to me in PNG or SVG but I am not sure it would render properly on each device or how to integrate it in SVG in order to have a nice scalable/responsive design for phones, tablets etc.
Do you know of any package or library helping to manage this type of problematic? (Just for information, the wave is static and not animated at all).

Thank you for the time.

[image: example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just ask the designer to send it in SVG and use this package: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg

You don't have to worry about responsivness since SVGs are scallable and won't lose quality(as you probably know already) it should look the same on all devices.

Comment: thanks for the package that’s what I was looking for, I’ll be able to integrate some SVG thanks a lot

Comment: No problem, don't forget to make this answer correct so other people that look up this question know this is the right package to use :D